# Linker errors using MySQL Connector C++ lib I built in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, linker-errors

### Summary

AFAICT, the only pre-built [Connector/C++ library](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/) that MySQL provides for Windows was built using Visual Studio 2010. I'm using Visual Studio 2013, so I need to build from source. I want to use the static library.

Below is a rough description of the steps I took. I am able to build the library (`mysqlcppconn-static.lib`), and I can add it as a dependency and `#include` headers my project. But once I try to actually use the library, I get a whole bunch of linker errors.

I played with the project properties, but I'm still stuck. How can I get this to work?

### Details

#### Project/Solution Construction Steps

1. Use [`cmake`](https://cmake.org/) for Windows with the `-DMYSQLCLIENT_STATIC_LINKING=true` and `-G "Visual Studio 12 2013"` options to create the project and solution files. Include `-D` parameters with paths for boost and the pre-built `mysql-connector-c-6.1.6-win32`.
2. Open MYSQLCPPCONN.sln in Visual Studio, and build the mysqlcppconn-static project.
3. Create a new VS solution and console application project in which I'll use the Connector/C++.
4. Extract the pre-built Connector/C++ library .zip file, replace `mysqlcppconn-static.lib` with those I built (Debug & Release), and setup paths accordingly.
5. Configuration Properties --> C/C++ --> Preprocessor --> Preprocessor Definitions: add `CPPCONN_PUBLIC_FUNC=`.

#### Linker Errors Summary

```
error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2'
error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug'
warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _memmove (et al) imported
warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _memmove imported in function...
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___CrtDbgReportW (et al)
```

#### Project Properties

I've been playing with the project properties in `mysqlcppconn-static`, and in my project that uses the library, trying to get them to match, but these errors persist.

Here are some potentially relevant project properties that are set identically in both projects:

```
Configuration Properties --> C/C++ --> Code Generation
  --> Basic Runtime Checks
        Debug   - /RTC1
        Release - Default
  --> Runtime Library
        Debug   - Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)
        Release - Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)
```

And in my project (which uses the connector), I have this linker property:

```
Configuration Properties --> Linker --> Input --> Ignore Specific Default Libraries
        Debug   - MSVCRTD.lib
        Release - MSVCRT.lib
```

---

#### More of the Mess of Linker Errors

```
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(net_serv.obj)                        : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in useMySQLConnectorCpp.obj
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(net_serv.obj)                        : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in useMySQLConnectorCpp.obj
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(plugin_client.obj)                   : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in useMySQLConnectorCpp.obj
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(plugin_client.obj)                   : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in useMySQLConnectorCpp.obj
[snip]
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_native_statement_wrapper.obj)  : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _memmove imported
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_art_rset_metadata.obj)         : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _memmove imported
[snip]
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_native_connection_wrapper.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _memmove imported in function "public: __thiscall std::_String_alloc<0,struct std::_String_base_types<char,class std::allocator<char> > >::~_String_alloc<0,struct std::_String_base_types<char,class std::allocator<char> > >(void)" (??1?$_String_alloc@$0A@U?$_String_base_types@DV?$allocator@D@std@@@std@@@std@@QAE@XZ)
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_art_resultset.obj)             : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _memmove imported
[snip]
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_client_api.obj)                : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _memmove imported
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_uri.obj)                       : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _memmove imported in function "public: void __thiscall std::_Wrap_alloc<class std::allocator<char> >::deallocate(char *,unsigned int)" (?deallocate@?$_Wrap_alloc@V?$allocator@D@std@@@std@@QAEXPADI@Z)
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_metadata.obj)                  : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _memmove imported in function __catch$?getProcedures@MySQL_ConnectionMetaData@mysql@sql@@UAEPAVResultSet@3@ABVSQLString@3@00@Z$0
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_warning.obj)                   : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _memmove imported
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_prepared_statement.obj)        : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _memmove imported
1>useMySQLConnectorCpp.obj                                     : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _memmove imported in function "public: static char * __cdecl std::char_traits<char>::move(char *,char const *,unsigned int)" (?move@?$char_traits@D@std@@SAPADPADPBDI@Z)
[snip]
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_native_driver_wrapper.obj)     : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _memmove imported
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_native_statement_wrapper.obj)  : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __hypot imported
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_art_rset_metadata.obj)         : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __hypot imported in function "public: void __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::_Copy(unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?_Copy@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAEXII@Z)
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_resultset_metadata.obj)        : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __hypot imported
[snip]
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_native_resultset_wrapper.obj)  : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __hypot imported
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_native_connection_wrapper.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __hypot imported in function "public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_art_resultset.obj)             : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __hypot imported
[snip]
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_client_api.obj)                : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __hypot imported
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_uri.obj)                       : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __hypot imported in function "public: char * __thiscall std::_Wrap_alloc<class std::allocator<char> >::allocate(unsigned int)" (?allocate@?$_Wrap_alloc@V?$allocator@D@std@@@std@@QAEPADI@Z)
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_metadata.obj)                  : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __hypot imported in function __catch$?getUniqueNonNullableKeys@MySQL_ConnectionMetaData@mysql@sql@@QAEPAVResultSet@3@ABVSQLString@3@00@Z$0
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_warning.obj)                   : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __hypot imported
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_prepared_statement.obj)        : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __hypot imported
1>useMySQLConnectorCpp.obj                                     : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __hypot imported in function _hypot
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_driver.obj)                    : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __hypot imported
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_connection.obj)                : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __hypot imported
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_native_driver_wrapper.obj)     : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __hypot imported
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_client_api.obj)                : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __invalid_parameter imported in function "public: void __thiscall std::_Tree_alloc<0,struct std::_Tree_base_types<struct std::pair<class sql::SQLString const ,class boost::shared_ptr<class sql::mysql::NativeAPI::IMySQLCAPI> >,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<class sql::SQLString const ,class boost::shared_ptr<class sql::mysql::NativeAPI::IMySQLCAPI> > > > >::_Free_proxy(void)" (?_Free_proxy@?$_Tree_alloc@$0A@U?$_Tree_base_types@U?$pair@$$CBVSQLString@sql@@V?$shared_ptr@VIMySQLCAPI@NativeAPI@mysql@sql@@@boost@@@std@@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBVSQLString@sql@@V?$shared_ptr@VIMySQLCAPI@NativeAPI@mysql@sql@@@boost@@@std@@@2@@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ)
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_art_resultset.obj)             : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __invalid_parameter imported
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_ps_resultset.obj)              : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __invalid_parameter imported
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_resultset.obj)                 : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __invalid_parameter imported
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_driver.obj)                    : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __invalid_parameter imported in function "public: bool __thiscall std::_Tree_const_iterator<class std::_Tree_val<struct std::_Tree_simple_types<struct std::pair<class sql::SQLString const ,class boost::shared_ptr<class sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver> > > > >::operator==(class std::_Tree_const_iterator<class std::_Tree_val<struct std::_Tree_simple_types<struct std::pair<class sql::SQLString const ,class boost::shared_ptr<class sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver> > > > > const &)const " (??8?$_Tree_const_iterator@V?$_Tree_val@U?$_Tree_simple_types@U?$pair@$$CBVSQLString@sql@@V?$shared_ptr@VMySQL_Driver@mysql@sql@@@boost@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QBE_NABV01@@Z)
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_connection.obj)                : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __invalid_parameter imported
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_metadata.obj)                  : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __invalid_parameter imported
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_prepared_statement.obj)        : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __invalid_parameter imported
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_resultbind.obj)                : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol ??0exception@std@@QAE@ABQBD@Z (public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(char const * const &)) imported
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_resultset.obj)                 : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol ??0exception@std@@QAE@ABQBD@Z (public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(char const * const &)) imported
[snip]
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_resultbind.obj)                : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol ??0exception@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z (public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(class std::exception const &)) imported
[snip]
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_resultbind.obj)                : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol ??1exception@std@@UAE@XZ (public: virtual __thiscall std::exception::~exception(void)) imported
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_resultset.obj)                 : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol ??1exception@std@@UAE@XZ (public: virtual __thiscall std::exception::~exception(void)) imported
[snip]
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_connection.obj)                : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __strnicmp imported in function __catch$?prepareStatement@MySQL_Connection@mysql@sql@@UAEPAVPreparedStatement@3@ABVSQLString@3@@Z$0
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_connection.obj)                : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol ?name@type_info@@QBEPBDPAU__type_info_node@@@Z (public: char const * __thiscall type_info::name(struct __type_info_node *)const ) imported in function "public: int * __thiscall sql::BaseVariantImpl::get<int>(void)const " (??$get@H@BaseVariantImpl@sql@@QBEPAHXZ)
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_uri.obj)                       : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _atoi imported in function "bool __cdecl sql::mysql::parseUri(class sql::SQLString const &,class sql::mysql::MySQL_Uri &)" (?parseUri@mysql@sql@@YA_NABVSQLString@2@AAVMySQL_Uri@12@@Z)
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_metadata.obj)                  : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _atoi imported in function __catch$?getColumnPrivileges@MySQL_ConnectionMetaData@mysql@sql@@UAEPAVResultSet@3@ABVSQLString@3@000@Z$0
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_metadata.obj)                  : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __snprintf imported in function __catch$?getImportedKeys@MySQL_ConnectionMetaData@mysql@sql@@UAEPAVResultSet@3@ABVSQLString@3@00@Z$0
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_art_resultset.obj)             : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __snprintf imported
[snip]
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_metadata.obj)                  : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _tolower imported in function "public: int __thiscall sql::SQLString::caseCompare(class sql::SQLString const &)const " (?caseCompare@SQLString@sql@@QBEHABV12@@Z)
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_prepared_statement.obj)        : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol ??0exception@std@@QAE@ABQBDH@Z (public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(char const * const &,int)) imported in function "public: __thiscall std::bad_alloc::bad_alloc(void)" (??0bad_alloc@std@@QAE@XZ)
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_debug.obj)                     : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _getenv imported in function "public: __thiscall sql::mysql::MySQL_DebugLogger::MySQL_DebugLogger(void)" (??0MySQL_DebugLogger@mysql@sql@@QAE@XZ)
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_debug.obj)                     : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _printf imported in function "public: void __thiscall sql::mysql::MySQL_DebugLogger::enter(class sql::mysql::MySQL_DebugEnterEvent const *)" (?enter@MySQL_DebugLogger@mysql@sql@@QAEXPBVMySQL_DebugEnterEvent@23@@Z)
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_debug.obj)                     : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _vprintf imported in function "public: void __cdecl sql::mysql::MySQL_DebugLogger::log_va(char const * const,char const * const,...)" (?log_va@MySQL_DebugLogger@mysql@sql@@QAAXQBD0ZZ)
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_debug.obj)                     : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _strstr imported in function "public: __thiscall sql::mysql::MySQL_DebugEnterEvent::MySQL_DebugEnterEvent(unsigned int,char const * const,char const * const,class boost::shared_ptr<class sql::mysql::MySQL_DebugLogger> const &)" (??0MySQL_DebugEnterEvent@mysql@sql@@QAE@IQBD0ABV?$shared_ptr@VMySQL_DebugLogger@mysql@sql@@@boost@@@Z)
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_ps_resultset_metadata.obj)     : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _strstr imported in function "char * __cdecl std::_Allocate<char>(unsigned int,char *)" (??$_Allocate@D@std@@YAPADIPAD@Z)
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_resultset_metadata.obj)        : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _strstr imported
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_util.obj)                      : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _strtod imported in function "long double __cdecl sql::mysql::util::strtold(char const *,char * *)" (?strtold@util@mysql@sql@@YAOPBDPAPAD@Z)
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_art_resultset.obj)             : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __strtoi64 imported in function "public: __int64 __thiscall sql::mysql::MyVal::getInt64(void)" (?getInt64@MyVal@mysql@sql@@QAE_JXZ)
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_ps_resultset.obj)              : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __strtoi64 imported in function "public: __thiscall sql::SQLException::SQLException(class sql::SQLException const &)" (??0SQLException@sql@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_resultset.obj)                 : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __strtoi64 imported
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_art_resultset.obj)             : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __strtoui64 imported in function "public: unsigned __int64 __thiscall sql::mysql::MyVal::getUInt64(void)" (?getUInt64@MyVal@mysql@sql@@QAE_KXZ)
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_ps_resultset.obj)              : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __strtoui64 imported in function __unwindfunclet$??0SQLException@sql@@QAE@ABV01@@Z$0
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_resultset.obj)                 : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __strtoui64 imported
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_client_api.obj)                : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___CrtDbgReportW
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_art_resultset.obj)             : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___CrtDbgReportW
[snip]
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_native_statement_wrapper.obj)  : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___wassert
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_art_rset_metadata.obj)         : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___wassert
[snip]
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_uri.obj)                       : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__memchr referenced in function "public: static char const * __cdecl std::char_traits<char>::find(char const *,unsigned int,char const &)" (?find@?$char_traits@D@std@@SAPBDPBDIABD@Z)
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_metadata.obj)                  : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__memchr
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_resultset.obj)                 : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__div referenced in function "public: virtual __int64 __thiscall sql::mysql::MySQL_ResultSet::getInt64(unsigned int)const " (?getInt64@MySQL_ResultSet@mysql@sql@@UBE_JI@Z)
```

Comment: You will find the answer for this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41991083/mysql-c-connector-unresolved-dependencies-vs-2015/54008937#54008937 Enjoy.

Comment: for me it worked fine for release build only after adding `mysqlcppconn.lib` instead of `mysqlcppconn-static.lib` as a dependency even though the documentation refers to `mysqlcppconn-static.lib`, and also the dll (in my case `mysqlcppconn-9-vs14.dll`) needs to get copied into the execution folder.